# Force, acceleration, and velocity with Javascript

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I am attempting to make objects move on screen based on force on the x-axis and y-axis. It seems to work properly when a force is applied to an object, but when the force is no longer applied, instead of the object continuing at the same velocity and direction, it goes off in a different direction with a different velocity. Is the error in this section of code? This is the only part I can  think would be the problem.

```
var update = function (modifier) {  
// rock going up/down wh
    if(rocks[i].y > 0 && rocks[i].y < worldSizeY){
        if(rocks[i] != null){
            rocks[i].accelerationy = rocks[i].forcey/rocks[i].mass;
            rocks[i].velocityy += (modifier*1000)*rocks[i].accelerationy;
            rocks[i].y += (modifier*1000)*rocks[i].velocityy;
        }
    }
// rock going right/left
    if(rocks[i].x < worldSizeX && rocks[i].x > 0){
        if(rocks[i] != null){
            rocks[i].accelerationx = rocks[i].forcex/rocks[i].mass;
            rocks[i].velocityx += (modifier*1000)*rocks[i].accelerationx;
            rocks[i].x += (modifier*1000)*rocks[i].velocityx;
        }
    }
    rocks[i].forcex = 0;
    rocks[i].forcey = 0;
}
```

Comment: would you happen to have a jsfiddle example, maybe?

Comment: You need to include sample input (e.g. a *rocks[i]* object with initial values, values for *modifier*), what you expect to get (final *rocks[i]* object and values) and what you actually get.

Comment: The fact that you've split the processing of the x and y components of the vectors seems a little odd, as does the position of the `if (rocks[i] !=null)` check - it should only be in the code you show once - it should occur _before_ an attempt to read the `x` or `y` values.

Comment: I'd highly recommend using a library for implementing physics. Developing game physics gets more and more complicated and they're no reason to reinvent the wheel